# CSS pre-wrap newline at the end of a string

Tags: javascript, html, css, newline, whitespace

When new line is inserted at the end of a string in an element which should with `whitespace: pre-wrap` style, I expected that a new line will appear.

However it seems that browsers convert the single new line and visible new line appears only when another character is inserted after the new line.

The Javascript that inserts the new line and an additional space:

```js
(function() {
    var cnt = document.getElementById('cnt')
    document.getElementById('btn').onclick = function() {
        cnt.textContent = cnt.textContent + String.fromCharCode(10)
    }
    document.getElementById('btn2').onclick = function() {
        cnt.textContent = cnt.textContent + " "
    }
})();
```

```html
<button id="btn">click to add new line</button>
<button id="btn2">click to add space</button>
<div id="cnt" style="width:500px; white-space: pre-wrap; border:1px solid black;">line</div>
```

For convenience demonstrated here https://jsfiddle.net/psimon/n9enuvn6/

Can anyone point me to a spec where this behaviour is defined and is there a known workaround? Tried searching, but so far nothing.

I've found out that I can insert carriage return together with new line and then I would only need to check on backspace and delete to remove them at once.

Comment: Post a complete code example *in your question* please. I'm sure you saw the warning about linking to jsFiddle without code in your question, and decided to try and sidestep that rule by highlighting one CSS rule as code. However that rule is in place for your benefit and ours.

Comment: Sorry, honestly overlooked that warning. Thanks for the reminder.